# Interbase DB JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc, gdb, interbase, gdbserver

I'm trying to connect to a legacy `interbase` database using `jdbc`, here is my code

```
try {
    Class.forName("interbase.interclient.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:interbase://localhost/k1500.gdb","usrname","password");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("Select * from myTable");
    ResultSet set =  statement.getResultSet();
}catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this exception:

```
interbase.interclient.UnlicensedComponentException: [interclient] Unlicensed component: This version of InterClient refuses communication with InterBase version WI-V7.1.0.131/tcp 
See API reference for exception interbase.interclient.UnlicensedComponentException
at interbase.interclient.Connection.remote_ATTACH_DATABASE(Unknown Source)
at interbase.interclient.Connection.connect(Unknown Source)
at interbase.interclient.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at interbase.interclient.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at Application.main(Application.java:13)
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Looks like you need a license...

Comment: I know that but the license for this version is not available,it's a legacy system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to obtain a license for the appropriate version of Interbase.   (The fact that you are using a "legacy" version does not change that.)

The article [Licensing and Installation of InterBase 7](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33616) explains the different kinds of Interbase licenses, and how they are installed.

The [Embarcadero](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/interbase) site explains how to get an Interbase license.  I suggest you use the [Request a Quote](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/quote-request) form if you have difficulty finding the version that you want.

It is also possible that your organization already / still has a license, and you / they have mislaid it.